# How to map strings in a Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-wrangling

Is there a way to `map` `characters` for a `column` in `Pandas`.

For example, I would like to map a column say `info` like this {"1": "US", "2":"DE", "3":"CA", "4":"AU", "5":"BE"}

So instead of the numbers, I would like something `US` and the rest to show

**EDIT NOTE: I dont want to explode the column, I want to keep them as they are, only replacing numbers with strings**

```
0   ['3']
1   ['6']
2   ['3','4']
3   ['3','4','6']
4   ['3','4']
5   ['6']
6   ['6']
7   ['5']
8   ['5']
9   ['3', '4', '1']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you could do:

```
d = {"1": "US", "2":"DE", "3":"CA", "4":"AU", "5":"BE"}
df.dropna().explode('my_col').my_col.map(d).groupby(level=0).agg(list).reindex(df.index)
```

Comment: No, I do not want to explode it

Comment: You will have the same structure after by gruopbing on the index again @A.JT ...

Comment: Check the row with NaN maybe

Comment: mmm not sure how to handle, don't have time now :/ @yoben

Comment: dropna, and explode , then reindex back ~

Answer (score 1):

If you don't wanna explode, use apply. But remember the explode method may be way faster than this on large dataframes

Test Dataframe

```
>>> df
        test
0     [3, 4]
1        [6]
2        [3]
3  [3, 4, 6]
```

Mapping dictionary

```
>>> info =  {"1": "US", "2":"DE", "3":"CA", "4":"AU", "5":"BE"}
```

#### CODE

```
>>> df.test.apply(lambda x: [info.get(str(i)) for i in x])
0          [CA, AU]
1            [None]
2              [CA]
3    [CA, AU, None]
Name: test, dtype: object
```